# Editing JLabel from JTextField in another class

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

I've looked around but nothing seems to help me out. Basically I'm writing a multithreaded chat program with a gui. The user inputs his name in a textfield in a Login class and hits the login button which directs him to a ClientGUI class. In the client GUI class theres a JLabel at the top that says

> "Welcome to the ChatSystem (Username)"

. So what the user input in the textfield in the login class should appear in the JLabel after "Welcome to the ChatSystem" but I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Here's my code:

Login Class:

```
loginB = new JButton("Login");
main.add(loginB);
loginB.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ClientGUI clientgui = new ClientGUI();
        clientgui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

ClientGUI class:

```
public ClientGUI(){
    Login login = new Login();
    String username = login.usernameTF.getText();
    welcome = new JLabel("Welcome to ChatSystem "+username, SwingConstants.CENTER);

}
```

I understand that username should really by a JLabel and not a String but I have tried many ways to do this and I can't seem to get my head around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not going to work like that because
`login.usernameTF.getText();` is actually a new created object in the **ClientGUI** constructor...

what I would suggest to do is to overload the constructor and to pass the name as parameter...

## Example:

```
 loginB.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     ClientGUI clientgui = new ClientGUI(getTheNameAndpassItHere);
     clientgui.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
```

---

and then ClientGUI class:

```
public ClientGUI(String username){

    //Login login = new Login();
   // String username = login.usernameTF.getText();

    welcome = new JLabel("Welcome to ChatSystem "+username, SwingConstants.CENTER);

}
```

Comment: thanks, it seems to work but if you can explain to me why creating a new object inside the constructor doesn't do the deal it would be helpful

Comment: is not because inside of the constructor, it is because you are creating a new login and all the date is new, and has nothing to do with the login you has before

Comment: ok I understand now thanks. I get another problem tho, inside my main method in ClientGUI, when I set the frame visible like this: "new ClientGUI(username).setVisible(true);" I get an error, it says username cannot be resolved to a variable. Do you know how to fix this? Sorry I know it must be a stupid question, but I'm fairly new in Java

Comment: is user name a string?? if yes where is that defined?

Comment: username is a string defined outside the constructor. Inside the constructor I call this.username = username to match the constructor parameter of username. It then tells me where it says "new ClientGUI(username).setVisible(true);" under username to change it to static. From past experience, I've been told never to change variables to static unless I understand why it's being done

Comment: yes, its a class variable, its NOT inside any method.

Comment: any ideas or should I just change the variable to static?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you should use a [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html), which allows `ClientGUI` to generate events to interested parties when something changes.

This decouples your code and prevents the `ClientGUI` from doing things it shouldn't (like removing the label or it's parent component for example)

You could use some of the inbuilt listeners if they meet your needs, but for something like this, I'd prefer to use my own

```
public class LoginEvent extends EventObject {

    private Throwable cause;
    private String userName;

    public LoginEvent(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }

    public Throwable getCause() {
        return cause;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

}

public interface LoginListener extends EventListener {
    public void loginFailed(LoginEvent evt);
    public void loginSuccessful(LoginEvent evt);
}
```

Then you could add an instance of the listener to the `ClientGUI`...

```
loginB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ClientGUI clientgui = new ClientGUI(getTheNameAndpassItHere);
        clientgui.addLoginListener(new LoginListener() {
            @Override
            public void loginFailed(LoginEvent evt) {
                Throwable cause = evt.getCause();
                // Show error message
            }

            @Override
            public void loginSuccessful(LoginEvent evt) {
                String name = evt.getUserName();
                // Update UI
            }
        });
        clientgui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

or something simular

Comment: getting the text and passing it through the ClientGUI seemed to work, but I'm interested in other ways of doing it too. I read a bit about observer patterns to see how they work but didn't seem to understand much (I'm a fairly new programmer). Could you explain what advantage your method has over just getting the text and passing it through the constructor (if any) please?

Comment: If you ass the label to the `ClientGUI`, the `ClientGUI` will; 1- ALWAYS require a `JLabel`, so suddenly if you want to update other aspects of the UI, you suddenly need to pass more objects to it. What happens if you don't want to update the UI with a `JLabel`, maybe a `JTextField` instead? You've tightly coupled the two together which makes it difficult to expand or modify; 2- It's not really the responsibility of the `ClientGUI` to update the UI in this way; 3- Not the `ClientGUI` can do things to your UI you didn't want it to. Nothing is stopping it from removing the label, as an example

Comment: hmm but aren't you passing the name through the ClientGUI constructor too?

Comment: No, you're passing a "contract" which limits what `ClientGUI` knows about you and what it can do, passes the responsibility to responding to  the event and what you do about it back to the observer and decouples the code, because you can pass what ever implementation of the observer you want and it won't change the functionality of `ClientGUI`

Comment: In many cases, instead of passing it the constructor, you might use a `add` method to add as many observers as you need, but this is not a requirement

Comment: Think about it this way, if you pass me a JLabel, I can do sorts of nasty things you're not expecting or wanting, change the color, change the font, set the text to whatever I want, but I can also gain access to the parent container, I could remove or add other components, change the layout and other properties of the container, but I can also gain access to the window and could close it, all without you been able to stop me

Answer (score 0):

the swings component are by default private you need to make them public by just little steps
1.go to the properties of the component and then to the code tab
[image]
2.you will find variable modifier as private make them public and as well as static if you want.
[image]

you will now be able to use the components with the same code

Comment: I don't think changing the protection value of a variable would be the best approach, but maybe adding an accessor and mutator to the variable instead.